# How to show a Polyline trace a different Polyline on MKmapview and follow?

Tags: swift, xcode, mapkit, mkmapview, mkpolyline

I have one polyline that shows lines when opening the app but when I search and clicking direction, the other polyline goes to the location B (As what I searched0) BUT I WANT IT TO FOLLOW THE POLYLINE THAT IS SHOWN ON THE APP RIGHT AWAY. I want it to follow the trace that is shown on the screen when opening the app.

Can someone please help me understand what I need to do? Thanks
I have been trying to figure it out but no clue so far.